# React-redux-firebase populate with createStructuredSelector from reselect

Tags: react-native, populate, reselect, react-redux-firebase

im using `react-redux-firebase` with `populate` method to mix data from collection and everything fine except i can't using `createStructuredSelector` with `mapStateToProps` from redux because createStructuredSelector replace it so i looking for solution how to combine this to things

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  const items = populate(state.firestore, 'Skill', populates);

  const seletors = createStructuredSelector({
    loading: makeSelectFSCollectionStatus('requesting', COLLECTION),
    skills: makeSelectFSCollectionOrdered(COLLECTION),
  });
  return seletors;
}
```

i need to insert `items` into `seletors` somehow

Answer (score 0):

found solution

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  const items = populate(state.firestore, 'Skill', populates);

  const seletors = createStructuredSelector({
    loading: makeSelectFSCollectionStatus('requesting', COLLECTION),
    skills: makeSelectFSCollectionOrdered(COLLECTION),
  });

  const t: any = seletors(state);
  t.items = items;

  return t;
};
```